# Using the apxproof package and \newtheoreprep, my theorems don't show up in the appendix.

Tags: theorems, appendices, proof-package, newtheorem

### Problem

A theorem environment was defined with `apxproof`'s `\newtheoremrep` command. The theorem however, doesn't show up in the appendix, and neither does the subsequent `\proof` as claimed by the package documentation.

E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apxproof}
\newtheoremrep{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\section{We test apxproof}

\begin{theorem}
This is the theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
This is the proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

### Solution

See Q&A answer.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly embarrassingly, I found the mistake to be a case of "RTFM(b)"<sup>*</sup>. Skimming the documentation, I wrongly assumed, that `\newtheoremrep{theorem}{Theorem}` causes the `theorem` environment to be always repeated.

What the command *actually* does, is

- Create a `theorem` environment as `\newtheorem` would.
- Create a `theoremrep` environment, that has the desired "repeat in appendix" behavior.

The correct usage therefore is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apxproof}
\newtheoremrep{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\section{We test apxproof}

\begin{theoremrep}                 % <- swap theorem for theoremrep
This is the theorem.
\end{theoremrep}
\begin{proof}
This is the proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Reading the f** manual (better).